# How to display the premise and consequence when the setCar is set to true?

Tags: java, machine-learning, associations, weka, data-mining

I want to get the premise and consequence for each line of generated rules after the running the apriori algorithm in Weka 3.8.0.

```
        apriori.setNumRules(NUMBER_OF_RULES);
        apriori.setMinMetric(MINIMUM_CONFIDENCE);
        apriori.setLowerBoundMinSupport(MINIMUM_SUPPORT);

        apriori.setCar(true);

        apriori.buildAssociations(instances);
```

I tried the code below to get the rules but it gives me an exception
(weka.associations.ItemSet cannot be cast to weka.associations.AprioriItemSet):

```
        AssociationRules arules = apriori.getAssociationRules();
```

Also, I tried using the getAllTheRules() method but it gives me a different result.

```
    ArrayList<Object>[] arules = apriori.getAllTheRules();
    System.out.println(((ItemSet)arules[0].get(1)).getRevision()); //12014
    System.out.println(((ItemSet)arules[0].get(2)).getRevision()); //12014
    System.out.println(((ItemSet)arules[0].get(5)).getRevision()); //12014
```